# PowerShell Workflow scoping issue

Tags: powershell, scope, workflow

Recently we started exploring Workflows in PowerShell. It greatly enhances the execution speed, but it adds an extra level of complexity too.

The code below has a scoping issue. The variables in the `Parallel` clause (`$Workflow:Ports` and `$Workflow:Drivers`) ar apparently shared over the different `$ComputerNames` instead of being specific to one `$ConputerName`. When checking [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574187(v=ws.11).aspx) I can't seem to figure out how to make the variables `$Ports` and `$Drivers` specific to that computer (`$C`).

When using `$Workflow:Ports` they are shared between all computers, and this is not what we want. When using `$Ports` it's not available in the `InlineScript` clause.

**The code:**

```
Workflow Get-PrintersInstalledHC {
    Param (
        [String[]]$ComputerName
    )

    Foreach -Parallel ($S in $ComputerName) {
        $Computer = InlineScript {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ComputerName   = $Using:S
                ComputerStatus = $null
                Printers       = $null
                RetrievalDate  = Get-Date
            }
        }

        # $VerbosePreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$Using:VerbosePreference
        Try {
            $Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $S -Full -EA Stop

            if ($Printers) {
                Write-Verbose "$S Found $($Printers.Count) printers"

                Parallel {
                    $Workflow:Ports = Get-PrinterPort -ComputerName $S
                    $Workflow:Drivers = Get-PrinterDriver -ComputerName $S
                }

                $CimConfig = InlineScript {
                    Try {
                        #region CmdLets that require admin permissions
                        $Params = @{
                            ComputerName = $Using:S
                            ClassName    = 'Win32_PrinterConfiguration'
                            Property     = '*'
                            ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
                            Verbose      = $false
                        } 
                        $Config = Get-CimInstance @Params
                        Foreach ($P in $Using:Printers) {
                            Foreach($C in $Config) {
                                if ($P.Name -eq $C.Name) {
                                    @{
                                        PrinterName      = $P.Name
                                        CimStatus        = 'Ok'
                                        DriverVersionCim = $C.DriverVersion
                                        Collate          = $C.Collate
                                        Color            = $C.Color
                                        Copies           = $C.Copies
                                        Duplex           = $C.Duplex
                                        PaperSize        = $C.PaperSize
                                        Orientation      = $C.Orientation
                                        PrintQuality     = $C.PrintQuality
                                        MediaType        = $C.MediaType
                                        DitherType       = $C.DitherType
                                    }
                                    Break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                    Catch {
                        Foreach ($P in $Using:Printers) {
                            @{
                                PrinterName  = $P.Name
                                CimStatus    = 'No admin permissions'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Foreach -parallel ($P in $Printers) {
                    $PrinterConfig = InlineScript {
                        $P = $Using:P
                        $Port = $Using:Ports | Where {$_.Name -eq $P.PortName}
                        $Driver = $Using:Drivers | Where {$_.Name -eq $P.DriverName}

                        Write-Verbose "$Using:S Printer '$($P.Name)'"

                        $DriverManufacturer = if ($Driver.Manufacturer) {$Driver.Manufacturer} else {
                            if ($Driver.Name -like '*Microsoft*') {'Microsoft'}
                        }

                        $DriverVersion = if ($Driver.DriverVersion -eq '0') {$null} else {
                            $Driver.DriverVersion
                        }

                        @{
                            Online_Hostname        = if ($P.Name) {Test-Connection $P.Name -Quiet -EA Ignore} else {$null}
                            Online_PortHostAddress = if ($Port.PrinterHostAddress) {Test-Connection $Port.PrinterHostAddress -Quiet -EA Ignore} else {$null}
                            PortHostAddress        = if ($Port.PrinterHostAddress) {$Port.PrinterHostAddress} else {$null}
                            PortDescription        = if ($Port.Description) {$Port.Description} else {$null}
                            DriverType             = $Driver.PrinterEnvironment -join ','
                            DriverManufacturer     = ($DriverManufacturer | Select -Unique) -join ','
                            DriverVersion          = ($DriverVersion | Select -Unique) -join ','
                        }
                    }

                    $Cim = $CimConfig | Where-Object -FilterScript {$P.Name -eq $_.PrinterName}

                    $P | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers ($PrinterConfig + $Cim) -TypeName NoteProperty
                }

                InlineScript {
                    $Computer = $Using:Computer
                    $Computer.Printers = $Using:Printers
                    $Computer.ComputerStatus = 'Ok'
                    $Computer
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Verbose "$S No printers found"
            }
        }
        Catch {
            InlineScript {
                $Computer = $Using:Computer

                if (Test-Connection $Using:S -Count 2 -Quiet) {
                    $Computer.ComputerStatus = $Using:_.Message
                }
                else {
                    $Computer.ComputerStatus = 'Offline'
                }

                $Computer
            }
        }
    }
}
```